# Normalize a SQL table - convert 1 row to 6 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

I have a table that is populated by data from a manufacturing system that needs to be normalized. This staging table has a key field - LOTCODE - plus 6 PARTSTATUS fields, a status code (INT) for PART1, PART2, etc.

Every hour I'd like to query the staging table and for each row found insert 6 rows into an archive table which would have key fields LOTCODE and PARTLOCATION plus a third field PARTSTATUS. Once the data is inserted in the archive table the row in the staging table would be deleted.

Is there a way to do this with just queries or do I need to loop though the staging table row by row, insert 6 rows in the archive table and then delete the original row?

The database is MS SQL 2016. Approximately 1440 rows will be added to the staging table each hour by the manufacturing system.

**Staging table sample row:**

```
Lot, Part1Status, Part2Status, Part3Status, Part4Status, Part5Status, Part6Status
ABCDE, 1010, 1010, -50, 1010, 990, 1010
```

**Archive table sample data**

```
Lot, PartLocation, Stats
ABCDE, 1, 1010
ABCDE, 2, 1010
ABCDE, 3, -50
ABCDE, 4, 1010
ABCDE, 5, 990
ABCDE, 6, 1010
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  This sounds like some pretty simple `insert` operations.

Comment: This operation is called "unpivot". There are many ways to do it -  `UNPIVOT` clause, `CROSS APPLY`, ...

Comment: @Jpoole . . . Why do you want to delete the rows in the staging table?  That seems like unnecessary overrhead.

Comment: No reason to keep the un-normalized data once it has been normalized in the archive table. There will be millions of rows which would also waste space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `TRY/CATCH` script that executes the `INSERT` and `DELETE` statements inside of an explicit transaction where `XACT_ABORT` has been set to `ON` which ensures a complete rollback of both DML statements in the event an exception is thrown.  Something like this

```
set nocount on;
set xact_abort on;

begin transaction
begin try
    declare @lc         table(LOTCODE int   unique not null);

    insert ArchiveTable(Lot, PartLocation, [Stats])
    output inserted.LOTCODE into @lc
    select LOTCODE, v.(
    from StagingTable st
         cross apply (values (1, st.Part1Status),
                             (2, st.Part2Status),
                             (3, st.Part3Status),
                             (4, st.Part4Status),
                             (5, st.Part5Status),
                             (6, st.Part6Status)) v(PARTLOCATION, [STATS]);

    delete st
    from StagingTable st
         join @lc lc on st.LOTCODE=lc.LOTCODE;

    commit transaction;
end try
begin catch
    /* throw / raiserror / logging */

    rollback transaction;
end catch
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to using Cross Apply vs UnPivot?

Comment: The advantage to CROSS APPLY is that it's more of a standard implementation across SQL's and to me it's more intuitive and readable than UNPIVOT.  It's like stacking bricks

Comment: Question - rather than bulk converting from the staging to archive table every hour could I just use an insert after trigger? Insert the data to the archive table and then delete the new staging record. Would the system doing the insert to the staging table see a fault, or "think" that the insert was successful?

Comment: Yes, you could use a trigger.  Depending on how it's coded it wouldn't interfere with existing processes